# How can I sustain commercial zones with just low/medium density residential zones?

Tags: cities-skylines-2

I cannot seem to be able to sustain commercial zones - they always complain about lack of customers unless I have high density residential areas around them, which are unlocked until level 8.

I have tried surrounding a small number of shops with lots of low/medium density residential zones but eventually they begin complaining.

How do I increase the number of customers without having to rely on high density residential zones in Cities Skylines 2?